# Linux command line - files by first line character count

Tags: linux, command-line

How can I search for all files on a server that have a first line with greater than X characters in the Linux command line?

Comment: **All files**? Every file in the entire filesystem? Or just files in one directory?  Or just files in one directory and its subdirectories?

Comment: @Robᵩ,  Every php or html file in public_html and all of its sub-directories

Answer (score 0):

```
X=4; find ~/public_html \( -name '*.html' -o -name '*.php' \) -print | while read f ; do (( $(head -1 $f | wc -c) > $X )) && echo $f  ; done
```

Comment: It's returning "Illegal variable name".  Sorry, I'm just familiar enough with this to be dangerous and can't figure out which variable it's talking about.